# Play drm protected video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, wget, youtube-dl, drm

I downloaded video from this link:-

https://zee5vod.akamaized.net/drm1/elemental/dash/TV_SHOWS/ZEE_TV/March2021/15032021/Seamless/BQC_Kumkum_Bhagya_CS_Ep1787_Seamless_15032021_hi_a2808b31106f106303f084b9943d5986/manifest1080lowp/1080lowp_000000649.mp4

> but when i am playing video then the video is not supported

someone help that how can i able to play this video

Answer (score 2):

1. This will download the video and audio file seperately. But both
   will be in encrypted format:

   ```
   yt-dlp --external-downloader aria2c --allow-unplayable-formats https://link.mpd -o fileName.mp4
   ```
2. Now once you have the encrypted audio and encrypted video file you'll need the key to decrypt these files. Once you have the key
   using the key to decrypt one at a time:

```
mp4decrypt --key keyFound --show-progress fileName.fvideo_avc1.mp4
DecryptedVideo.mp4

mp4decrypt --key keyFound --show-progress
fileName.faudio_und_mp4a.40.2.m4a DecryptedAudio.mp4
```

3. Now you have to merge the decrypted video and decrypted audio:

```
ffmpeg -i DecryptedVideo.mp4 -i DecryptedAudio.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac final.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things fundamentally wrong in your question.

First, this does not belong to StackOverflow as unrelated to prorgramming.

Second, the provided link does not represent a playable video. It is only a part of media asset, an incomplete part. Even if you could decrypt it by stripping DRM protection, you would still be unalble to play it "as a file" or "as a link".

Third, the whole point of DRM protection is that the data is encypted and you are supposed to play media with the help of, let's call it, "environment" which provides you with a service of secure temporary decryption just for the task of playback, secured well enough to prevent from non-authorized manipulation with he data. With this in mind, you are not supposed to be able to download the asset and play it back outside of the environment providing you with DRM-enabled playback services. It is the intentional behavior put into design of DRM protection to NOT allow you to download and play the data outside of protected environment (what you are trying to do and seeking for help for).